# Настраиваемый аудиоплеер на Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Я перерыл штук 100 разных плееров в гугл, но это что-то смешное. Я был уверен что легко найду много библиотек для использования, а не смог найти ни одной подходящей.

Мне нужен фиксированный плеер для сайта с возможностью загружать музыку из soundcloud(но на крайний случай можно и без него) и списком воспроизведения. Так же важно что бы он был настраиваемый, что бы настроить его под дизайн сайта. При этом адаптивный, что бы на мобильных устройствах он тоже работал качественно.

Я нашел вот этот плеер: http://www.mediaelementjs.com/, но он никак не адаптивный?, а так что бы прикрепить его к низу страницы придется переписать половину стилей и скрипта. НУ и в нем нет поддержки списков, что в принципе тоже можно решить через их API.

Хотелось бы узнать: может кто-то уже имел дело с этой проблемой? Как вы ее решили? Не хотелось бы писать скрипт с нуля.

Comment: Нашел https://wavesurfer-js.org/, вроде есть шансы на внедрение, но плейлисты отсутствуют и все элементы управления нужно добавить вручную. Но это пока что вариант который реально можно доделать до нужного состояния.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое решение: [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

Есть API для полного контроля всего, готовые варианты плееров и поддержка старых браузеров. В общем все что мне нужно было я нашел там. Но оказалась одна проблема. Все переключатели созданы с помощью ссылок, что портит дизайн прикрепленного к низу плеера при наведении на них. При наведении Chrome открывает серую строку слева внизу с адресом ссылки, а это поверх плеера.

Окончательное: [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/)

Как ни крути в итоге попал по всем рекомендациям в интернете на jPlayer. Примеры на сайте выглядят просто ужасно но когда я присмотрелся к коду, оказалось это довольно таки гибкий для редактирования плеер. Применив серию классов и изменений к структуре я смог сделать то что хотел.